# Condensing repetitive try-except statements in python

Tags: python, while-loop, try-except

I have a script that's asking the user to input a lot of dates, mostly in functions similar to the one below. These need to account for invalid date formats:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xlwings as xw
import datetime as dtt

def week_init():
        """Creates an initial week datetime and determines what the checking cutoff
        'beforeday' to be used in Stage 2 is."""
        week = input('Week to check: MM/DD/YYYY\n')
        switch = 1
        while switch == 1:
            try:
                week = dtt.datetime.strptime(week,'%m/%d/%Y') #turns input to a datetime
                switch = 0
            except ValueError:
                week = input('Unrecognized date format, please try again: MM/DD/YYYY\n')
        beforeday = (input('Check days before date (Press enter to use today): MM/DD/YYYY\n')
            or dtt.date.today())
        if (beforeday != dtt.date.today()):
            switch = 1
            while switch == 1:
                try:
                    beforeday = dtt.datetime.strptime(beforeday,'%m/%d/%Y')
                    switch = 0
                except ValueError:
                    beforeday = input('Unrecognized date format, please try again: MM/DD/YYYY\n')
        return week, beforeday
```

There are also functions that check an index for a given date, and have to deal with a given date not matching any of the indices:

```
def spotmap(week, bam, pt):
    """Maps the pivoted data for the chosen week to the BAM dataframe's SD column."""
    print('Mapping data to BAM... ',end=''),
    switch = 1
    while switch == 1:
        try:
            bam['SD'] = bam.index.to_series().map(pt.fillna(0)['len',week])
            switch = 0
        except KeyError:
            print('Invalid date, please try again.')
            week = input('Week start date (Sunday): MM/DD/YYYY\n')
    print('Done')
    return bam
```

As the script has a lot of things to do after it gets these dates, I don't want it to crash when it has a problem, but it can't proceed without correct date inputs so I currently have it looping with those "switch" variables controlling when it is willing to move on with a valid date. As you can see, though, these try/except blocks are rapidly bloating the otherwise straightforward code. Is there a way to condense these things? Also, a better method than the switches?

[Repetitive Try and Except Clauses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386592/repetitive-try-and-except-clauses)

The answers here suggested decorators, but as far as I can tell from the documentation and pages like [this](https://realpython.com/blog/python/primer-on-python-decorators/), those are for wrapping functions, not for replacing interior code blocks. Also I'm not sure how useful they'd be, because the try/except blocks are mostly unique in what they're trying to accomplish (ie, which variable they're changing). I guess I'm really just hoping for some better syntax.

Comment: [codereview.se] might be a better place to ask this at, I think.

Comment: Ah, ok. I'll do that, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping up your repeated calls in functions to decrease the bloat. Here's a stab at it:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xlwings as xw
import datetime as dtt

def loop_until_good(func, arg):
    looping = True
    while looping:
        (arg, looping) = func(arg)
        return arg

def make_datetime(date):
    try:
        date = dtt.datetime.strptime(date,'%m/%d/%Y') #turns input to a datetime
        return date, False
    except ValueError:
        date = input('Unrecognized date format, please try again: MM/DD/YYYY\n')
        return date, True

def bammit(arg):
    (bam, week, pt) = arg
    try:
        bam['SD'] = bam.index.to_series().map(pt.fillna(0)['len',week])
        return (bam, week, pt), False
    except KeyError:
        print('Invalid date, please try again.')
        week = input('Week start date (Sunday): MM/DD/YYYY\n')
        return (bam, week, pt), True

def week_init():
        """Creates an initial week datetime and determines what the checking cutoff
        'beforeday' to be used in Stage 2 is."""
        week = str(input('Week to check: MM/DD/YYYY\n'))
        print type(week)
        print week
        loop_until_good(make_datetime, week)
        beforeday = (input('Check days before date (Press enter to use today): MM/DD/YYYY\n')
            or dtt.date.today())
        if (beforeday != dtt.date.today()):
            loop_until_good(make_datetime, beforeday)
        return week, beforeday

def spotmap(week, bam, pt):
    """Maps the pivoted data for the chosen week to the BAM dataframe's SD column."""
    print('Mapping data to BAM... ')
    loop_until_good(bammit, (bam, week, pt))
    print('Done')
    return bam
```